# right to left jframe

Tags: java, jframe, right-to-left

How to create right to left jframe ?!

this is java original jframe
[image]

and this is the result when use :

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

[image]

but i need some thing like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is to use an undecorated frame with the Metal LAF:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE5
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE5");

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
        frame.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the result some thing like
http://i.stack.imgur.com/rF4Zt.png

i need some thing like 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/huWJC.png

Comment: I know. I said It will only work for the Metal LAF, not the default LAF which uses the WIndows default decorations. Swing can't control the look of the title bar on the frame because that is the frame of the platform. Swing can control the Metal LAF decorations because it paints the title bar itself.